# ipsec verify on ubuntu Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding [FAILED]

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec

Ubuntu 14.04, Openswan U2.6.38/K3.13.0-30-generic

When I run ipsec verify I get this error.

```
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding            [FAILED]
```

I see quite a few of this same question floating around. Has anybody finally found the solution?

Of course I've enabled IP forwarding in sysctl.conf :-)

I've done a ton of research and just cannot get by this.

Answer (score 8):

The gist of this is that the Ubuntu AMI's must use the NETKEY stack and that you must make configuration tweaks to support that. You also need to enable IP forwarding.

You will make these changes using the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and the `sysctl` command. This will cause changes in the `proc` file system at paths like `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirect`s, but by editing this file, you ensure those changes are reflected on reboot.

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add or uncomment the following lines:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 0
```

Now use the `sysctl` command to load your new configuration:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If you succeeded, running `$ sudo ipsec verify` again should show everything [OK].

Hope it could help.

Comment: I am running it inside a dcoker container, i have add all the kernel modules reuired for Strongswan ipsec, but it stills give me the error

`/usr/sbin/ipsec: unknown IPsec command verify (ipsec --help for list)`

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post](https://lists.openswan.org/pipermail/users/2013-July/022521.html) on the Opensswan mailing list, the error is caused by an old perl version and can be ignored.

Comment: It would be interesting to know which old version of Perl they were refering to.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/793972/ipsec-configuration-problems-on-ubuntu-errors-on-ip-forwarding-connection-auth) post solve it for me:

- echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
- ipsec verify

Comment: Yes but it will not persist at reboot without modifying the related `sysctl` configuration file.